# How to drop a row using iloc method

Tags: pandas

I dropped the first two **columns** using the iloc method in the following code without any problem.

```
eng_df.drop(eng_df.iloc[:,:2] , axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But I tried to delete the first **row** with the iloc method in the following code and it did not work:

```
eng_df.drop(eng_df.iloc[:1 , :] ,  inplace=True)
```

... and get the following warning:

KeyError: "['Country' 'Energy Supply' 'Energy Supply per Capita' '% Renewable'] not found in axis"

I know I can drop the row in different ways, but my question is can I drop rows with the iloc method, if so, how can I do that and  what is wrong in my codes? Thanks...

Comment: Why using .iloc you want to drop the code? `.iloc` is used mainly for extracting some particular rows and columns.
Try this if you want to drop using indices: `df.drop(df.index[0])`

Comment: The reason the first snippet works and not the second is that a dataframe is interpreted as an iterable of column names. In other words `[c for c in df]` is roughly the same as `df.columns`. The same goes if you replace `df` with `eng_df.iloc[:,:2]`.

Answer (score 5):

As per documentation of, `pandas.DataFrame.drop`

> Remove rows or columns by specifying label names and corresponding axis, or by specifying directly index or column names. When using a multi-index, labels on different levels can be removed by specifying the level.

So, for your code,

```py
# dropping columns
eng_df.drop(columns=eng_df.iloc[:,:2].columns.tolist(), inplace=True)

# dropping index
eng_df.drop(index=eng_df.iloc[:1, :].index.tolist(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: You don't need `tolist` do you?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me for dropping just one row:

```
dfcombo.drop(dfcombo.iloc[4].name)
```

Use iloc to get the row as a Series, then get the row's index as the 'name' attribute of the Series. Then use the index to drop.

For your example I guess it would be:

```
eng_df.drop(eng_df.iloc[0].name,  inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `.index`: `df_train_corr.drop(df_train_corr.iloc[1::2].index, inplace=True)`. This code deletes all odd rows.

Answer (score 1):

With pandas version 0.22.0 I believe this would work.

```
#to drop iloc 104
eng_df.drop(labels=104, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I believe this only works with an integer index, and interprets `104` as a label, not a position.